# onInstalled chrome runtime debugging?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){
    chrome.tabs.update(null, {url: ''});
    alert();
});
```

Above code doesn't work when I install my extension in developer mode. I want to update the active tab to be a blank tab once my extension installed in chrome web store.

Answer (score 0):

That's an invalid URL, that's why it does not work.

You can't just "erase" the URL without navigating to what you supply as the new URL.

If you are trying to navigate to the New Tab page, it has a URL (that's normally hidden) `chrome://newtab`. If you want a blank page in terms of content, it's `about:blank`.

Comment: Or use about:blank for an empty tab.

Comment: I have one more problem, executescript will got an error too if the user trigger it when they are at the pages like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps. It seems like bringing the user to a new blank tab after installation is not a perfect solution.

Comment: @DanielHerr my alert isn't got triggered when I drag my folder into the extension page, how to debug onInstalled?

Comment: @AaronMusktin Why do you need a blank page to begin with? Sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Xan because i trigger executeScript when the user click on my content of popup.html (browseraction), so in chrome web store page I got an error. That's why I thought of bringing them to somewhere after install, before they click something from the popup.html.

Comment: You probably should react to that _when_ `executeScript` fails (you can check for that), not randomly opening/redirecting on install. Also, maybe telling the user "can't script this page" is better? What does your script do?